# Switching between JPanels in different classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've stumbled upon this complications and have spent more than 4 hours debugging and googling but to no avail..

Basically what I have here is 1 JFrame, 2 JPanels.
I had my JFrame setContentPane to 1 of the JPanel, and when I run the Application, the JFrame will appear with the JPanel inside.

Now this JPanel have 1 JButton inside it, when I click it I want it to switch to another JPanel. As you can see from the code, when I click the JButton(Add Product), I want the OnlineShopAdPane to switch to AddProduct. I tried using CardLayout but it only has NSEW formatting.

```
package OnlineShop.ui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class OnlineShopMainFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    AddProduct Add;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OnlineShopMainFrame MainFrame = new OnlineShopMainFrame();
                    MainFrame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public OnlineShopMainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        OnlineShopAdPane AdPanel = new OnlineShopAdPane();
        setContentPane(AdPanel);

    }


}
```

```
package OnlineShop.ui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class OnlineShopAdPane extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */

    public OnlineShopAdPane() {

        JLabel lblWhatDoYou = new JLabel("What do you want to do?");
        lblWhatDoYou.setBounds(28, 26, 160, 26);
        add(lblWhatDoYou);

        JButton btnAddProduct = new JButton("Add Product");
        btnAddProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                OnlineShopMainFrame MainFrame = new OnlineShopMainFrame();
            MainFrame.removeAll();
            MainFrame.add(new AddProduct());
            MainFrame.revalidate();
            MainFrame.repaint();
            }
        });

        btnAddProduct.setBounds(46, 75, 115, 23);
        add(btnAddProduct);

    }

}
```

```
package OnlineShop.ui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class AddProduct extends JPanel {
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public AddProduct() {

        JLabel lblProductName = new JLabel("Product Name:");
        lblProductName.setBounds(35, 26, 77, 24);
        add(lblProductName);

        JLabel lblProductDescription = new JLabel("Product Description:");
        lblProductDescription.setBounds(10, 50, 106, 24);
        add(lblProductDescription);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(116, 28, 141, 20);
        add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(116, 66, 141, 112);
        add(textArea);

        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        btnClose.setBounds(223, 244, 89, 23);
        add(btnClose);

    }

}
```

Comment: **N** orth **S** outh **E** ast **W** est

Comment: `N orth S outh E ast W est` - that may be what it stands for, but what does it mean? There is no such thing as NSEW formatting as the OP is suggesting.

Comment: Follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should not start with an upper case character. "MainFrame" should be `mainframe`.

Comment: I'll take note of the naming convention, it became a bad habit of mine hehe.
I think I messed up myself with the NSEW formatting in the cardlayout. I'll try the CardLayout again to see if it will help me in my problem. Will get back to you guys about how it goes again~!

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I managed to solve the problem using the advice you've given!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using CardLayout but it only has NSEW formatting.

What does that mean? A CardLayout simply contains two or more panels. Only one panel is visible at a time. Each panel can use whatever layout it wants to layout the components on the panel.

> when I click it I want it to switch to another JPanel.

That is exactly what CardLayout does. See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example and explanation.

Whenever I see code like remove/add/revalidate/repaint it should almost always be replaced with a CardLayout

Comment: I tried CardLayout and it only enables me to have sort of like 1 swing component inside.
But I'll take your advice and try on CardLayout once more :) I'll get back to this topic again~ Thanks for your help

Comment: @kyle, You add a panel to a CardLayout. A panel can have as many components as you want added to it. Look at the tutorial, the panel has more than one component.

Comment: I followed what you suggested and it worked like a charm, thanks camickr!

Answer (score 0):

I think that with `CardLayout` you can resolve it, but another way is using for example a Handler to switch your panels.

```
    private JComponent container; // this could be your Frame
    private JComponent loadedComponent;

public void loadContent(JComponent component, Object object ) {

        if (loadedComponent != null) {
            loadedComponent.setVisible(false);
            container.remove(loadedComponent);
            loadedComponent = null;
        }
        //TODO may check layout
        container.add(component,object);
        component.setVisible(true);
        loadedComponent = component;
        container.validate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pobably located at the following lines in class `OnlineShopAdPane.java`

```
OnlineShopMainFrame MainFrame = new OnlineShopMainFrame();
MainFrame.removeAll();
MainFrame.add(new AddProduct());
MainFrame.revalidate();
MainFrame.repaint();
```

your not referring to the frame where your JPanel is nested. instead your creating a new `OnlineShopMainFrame`

Comment: I tried typing the following code into OnlineShopAdPane:
OnlineShopMainFrame MainFrame;

But it gave my error when I run the program..

Comment: this piece of code isn't new! I just wanted to give you a hint where your error comes from and whats the reason...

Comment: How do I refer to the frame where my JPanel is nested?

Comment: I found out how to refer to frame where the JPanel is a moment ago, thanks for highlighting it to me!